# How to trigger event when same value of angular kendo dropdown list is selected

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

In kendo dropdown list, there is a list of data and a value that is selected. When open the dropdown, if I click the same value that is selected, (valueChange) event won't be triggered. I have tried but in that case only (close) event can be triggered and I can't know which element is selected.

Can anyone help to give a hint if I can trigger event when same value is selected? Thanks!

Comment: You can only do something in open event, like clear selected value, thus after you selected some value,  which will triggle selectionchange again.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to get? Value? Data item?

You can get all that on `close` event:

```
close: function(e) {
  console.log(this.dataItem())
  console.log(e.sender.selectedIndex)
  console.log(this.value())
}
```

Example: [Close event](https://dojo.telerik.com/AToguTEr)